# CSS - Background image doesn't show, background color works fine

Tags: html, css, background-image

My problem is as follows: I replaced some items (navigation, footer) in my HTML-code by adding objects instead and loading them externally. Since I did that, I can't load background pictures into my 'collage' part of the website.

HTML: Stripped it off of everything not part of the problem (except for the content). 
The container is just a wrapper for the whole thing. My website will contain a bunch of images in the middle that link to the appropriate websites and, on hover over, display a short description and a title.

`.collage` is used to style the overall frame of the element
id will be used to add the background images (worked before!)

## HTML-Part:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
   <title>Startseite</title>
</head>

<html>
    <body>

    <div id="container">

        <article>       
            <div class="collage" id="cg">
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="text">

                        <h2>CG-Projekte</h2>
                        <p>
                            Computergerenderte Projekte, basierend auf         der Open-Source-Software 'Blender', sowie Tutorials für einige der Projekte.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

        </article>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Use the first part for general purposes.

**`body`**: `font-size` so I can scale all `em` elements with one value (mobile)

**`#container`**: Placed in the middle, positioned accordingly, slightly darker than the overall background. Pretty basic

**`article .collage`**: Display as table to make the image hover-over work properly (which it does even now)

**`#cg`**: The part that isn't working. I can change the background-color with this tag, but not the image

**`.text` parts**: Those are the designs for the hover-over part, they work as far as I can see. I am using **opacity** to make it invisible, until it is hovered over.

## CSS-Styling:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
   font-size: 100%;
   background-color:#2B2B2B;
}

#container{
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 100px;
min-height: 50em;
min-width: 70em;
max-width: 80em;
background-color: #2A2A2A;
border: 2px solid white;
}

article .collage {
display: table;
height: 500px;
width: 700px;
margin: 100px 0 0 5px;
border: 1px white solid;
}

#cg{
background: url("cg_collage.jpg");
}

article div .text{
    height: 400px;
    width: 800px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all ease-in 0.1s;
}
article .collage a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

article .collage .text{
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

article .collage .text h2{
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ADFF5C;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: monospace;
    border-bottom: 3px ridge #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 50px;
}

article .collage .text p{
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #ADFF5C;
}

article div:hover .text{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**Folders**

[image: My folder hierarchy]

As I said: I can change the background color fine, hover-over works perfectly. The only thing that won't work is the background-images. Images work fine if I embed them in the html-file.

I can't figure it out and a different viewpoint might find the **'Error 30'** ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the other answers are correct, in the sense that your paths are not correct. The reason why this is happening is b/c your CSS file is in, I'm assuming, the "styles" folder, and when you reference your image, the path is assuming that the image is in the same folder as your CSS file.

Instead of using ".." to "back out" of a folder, it's always a best practice to use relative paths. Reason being, if you move files, folders, etc, then the path will always be correct.

Hence, instead of using `background: url('../cg_collage.jpg')`, you should use `background: url('/cg_collage.jpg')`. The "/" at the beginning tells the file(s) to look at the root and start from there. So rather than always counting how many folder structures you need to "drop back", use relative paths.

Also, a good practice is to always have your images in a folder, and name that folder appropriately (eg - "img" or "images" or w/e).

Helpful article on [absolute and relative paths](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/).

Comment: I KNEW it was an Error 30.. 30 inches in front of the screen -.- Edit: However the '/' for root doesn't work. With the dots, it does. The images usually are in a folder, just got mad :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your CSS:

```
#cg{
  background: url("cg_collage.jpg");
}
```

To:

```
#cg{
  background: url("../cg_collage.jpg");
}
```

This is because your image is outside styles folder (where your stylesheet is).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but CSS is looking for image file in its direcotry (styles). Try this one:

```
#cg{
    background: url("../cg_collage.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works perfectly, when the file cg_collage.jpg is in folder /styles. Is it there in your project?

Comment: He already provides the folder structure as well. so code is not perfect.